# Scale android element according to different screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am facing problem with the scaling of "images", "text fields", "buttons", basically all the elements I have used in my layout.

[image]

If you see below, This is is a 5.5 inch resolution display and my application is looking perfect, but when I change screen resolution, my elements start overlapping. This is how it starts looking...

[image]

Elements starts overlapping eachother, can anyone help me with this issue? I have been struggling for 4 days now.

Below is the layout XML...

**ALSO I WAS DRAGGING THE SMALL CENTERED BUBBLES TO MATCH IT TO THE SCREEN SEND SO THAT I COULD BUILD, OTHERWISE I WAS GETTING BUILD ERROR, SO I DRAGGED THOSE BUBBLES TO EDGE OF THE SCREEN TO MAKE IT FIX**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/appbackgroundall">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/smartlever"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.294"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smartButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sansationregular"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:text="Tap to alter smart mode"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.433" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/allbackcologo"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/companylogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spaceman"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="253dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.868"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/spaceman" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pingedlogo"
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.058"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pingedlogo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/developerbutton"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingButton"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:rotation="175"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.923"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/settingbutton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingB"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/settingButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/settingButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/settingButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/settingButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.093"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.784"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alientwo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use minWidth and maxWidth,

> example :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.093"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.784"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alientwo" />
```